# CSS flex layout overflow issue

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to learn css flex layout but I ran into the following problem:

I have the following code:

```css
.my-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 25px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.fixedCol {
  padding: 12px !important;
  flex: 0 0 400px;
  border: 3px solid #b2e485;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.dynamicCol {
  padding: 12px !important;
  border-top: 3px solid #b2e485;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #b2e485;
  border-right: 3px solid #b2e485;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  .fixedCol {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }

  .dynamicCol {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    border: 3px solid #b2e485;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
 <div className="my-container">
  <div className="fixedCol">
    <h5>FIXED</h5>
  </div>
  <div className="dynamicCol">
    <h5>Dynamic</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to create a 2 column layout with the following characteristics:

- on screens bigger the 1100px: 1 column with 400px width and 1 column to fill the rest
  [image]
- on screens under 1100px: break columns in 2 rows

[image]

The problem that I have is when the content is bigger than the second column, the row breaks into 2 separate rows even if the screen is bigger than 1100xpx.How can I make the content to fit into second column but don't break de row?

[image]

EDIT: The problem was that the text was a single word. If I replace it with a paragraph it works well. But there is another problem: in my app the place will be replaced with some chart components. When I add those charts the same thing happens. Before I used the charts in a bootstrap 5 grid layout and it worked well without overflowing. (The charts are responsive)
[image]

Comment: If you don't want the container to wrap, then don't use `flex-wrap`.

Comment: If I don't use the wrap it overflows he screen size, I want the content to adapt his size to the column. The content of the second column will be a responsive chart which takes the the size of the column.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to handle the content:

1. Add "overflow: hidden" to the .dynamicCol class, to hide excess content.
2. Add "word-break: break-all" to the same class to make the word being broken up in several lines.
3. Make sure not to use words longer than what the container is supposed to be.

Comment: The content of the second column will be a series of charts that have a dynamical width based on the container. I used a bootstrap 5 grid layout with the same content and it worked but I don't want my column size to be percentage of the page(like bootstrap grid), but a fixed number of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

##### The reason why it is wrapping on 2nd row is in your container stylings:

```css
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

If you pass lots of text in your second box, it will try to squish it but, it wont work. So it it collapse to another row, becouse you allowed it to do so with `wrap` style.

You can fix it by removing the `flex-wrap: wrap` from `.my-container` and then setting a `flex-direction: column` in media query.

###### Quick snippet:

```css
.my-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 25px;
}

/* This will also prevent the content from overflowing */
.dynamicCol {
  word-break: break-all;
}

/* You should manualy adjust this value to fit your site */
@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  .my-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question, the problem is not the long word

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `flex-wrap` to stop the content from wrapping onto a new row.

Use [the `word-break` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) to allow the content to wrap even if there is an unbroken word which is longer than the available space.

And you can significantly simplify your CSS by applying the outer border to the container element rather than the two child elements.

```css
.my-container {
  margin: 25px;
  border: 3px solid #b2e485;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.fixedCol {
  padding: 12px;
  border-color: #b2e485;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 3px 0;
}

.dynamicCol {
  padding: 12px;
  word-break: break-word;
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  .my-container {
    display: flex;
  }
  .fixedCol {
    flex: 0 0 400px;
    border-width: 0 3px 0 0;
  }
  .dynamicCol {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <div class="fixedCol">
    <h5>FIXED</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="dynamicCol">
    <h5>Dynamic</h5>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="my-container">
  <div class="fixedCol">
    <h5>FIXED</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="dynamicCol">
    <h5>Dynamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamicamic</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="my-container">
    <div class="fixedCol">
        <h5>FIXED</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="dynamicCol">
        <h5>Dynamicccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is css code

```
.my-container {
    display: flex;
    margin: 25px;
}

.fixedCol {
    padding: 12px !important;
    flex: 0 0 400px;
    border: 3px solid #b2e485;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.dynamicCol {
    padding: 12px !important;
    border-top: 3px solid #b2e485;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #b2e485;
    border-right: 3px solid #b2e485;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    flex: 1;
}
.dynamicCol h5{
    word-break: break-all;
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
    .fixedCol {
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
        flex: 0 0 100%;
    }

    .dynamicCol {
        flex: 0 0 100%;
        border: 3px solid #b2e485;
        border-top: 0px;
        border-top-left-radius: 0px;
        border-top-right-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        }
    .my-container{
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question, the problem is not the long word